# Assigning a multidimensional array in single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi i have an array in  this format

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>array Name/index</td>
      <td>d1</td>
          <td>d2</td>
          <td>d3</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>d</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B</td>
          <td>S</td>
          <td></td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>C</td>
          <td></td>
      <td></td>

  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>A</td>
          <td></td>
      <td></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

now My task is to arrange this to a single array

$arr=array(A,B,d,B,s,C,A);
(getting all array with index wise)
 For this i have tried foreach , for loop but i m not getting proper result

(Please Note That These all array in table are generated from query)

Comment: These all is going in ajax call

Comment: then write your code

Answer (score 0):

```
//input array
$array = array(
            array('A','B','d'),
            array('B','s'),
            array('C'),
            array('A')
        );

$key_array = array();

foreach($array as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $element) {
        $key_array[$key][] = $element;
    }
}

$result = array();

foreach($key_array as $row) {
    foreach($row as $element) {
        $result[] = $element;
    }
}

print_r($result);


//result array
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => A
    [4] => B
    [5] => s
    [6] => d
)
```

Comment: Sir i want first index of all array then second and then third The output will be A,B,c a b s d

Comment: Why the complicated two-step process? That's entirely pointless. You can do `$result[] = $element` directly in your first loop.